# Convert string to uppercase in scala

Tags: string, scala, uppercase

```
class Student(firstName: String, lastName: String, rollNum: String)
```

need to convert firstName and lastName into uppercase. What is the best way in terms of design when we assign the values

```
val st1 = Student(
                  firstName = firstName.toUpperCase, 
                  lastName = lastName.toUpperCase, 
                  rollNum = rollNum
          )
```

or

```
case class UpperCaseStr(rawValue: String) {
   def value: String = rawValue.toUpperCase
}

val st1 = Student(
                  firstName = UpperCaseStr(firstName), 
                  lastName = UpperCaseStr(lastName), 
                  rollNum = rollNum
          )
```

Comment: The second approach does not compile. The first approach is correct.

Comment: If your domain has some rules for names I would create a separate type with smart constructor and use that type instead of String. If this is one time thing, I think `.toUpperCase` is enough.

Answer (score 2):

If your domain need to enforce some rules for names, I would create a smart constructor:

```
case class Name private (val value: String) {
  def copy(value: String = this.value) = Name(value)
}
object Name {
  def apply(value: String) = new Name(value.toUpperCase)
}
```

and use it instead of `String`

```
case class Student(firstName: Name, lastName: Name, rollNum: String)
```

If it was just one time thing that wouldn't serve domain modeling correctness I would just use a helper that would call `.toUpperCase` like @Markus Appel suggested.

Answer (score 0):

You should make `Student` a `case class`, otherwise it won't work.

Then, use a combination of `.copy` and `.toUpperCase`:

```scala
case class Student(firstName: String, lastName: String, rollNum: String)

def upperCaseStudent(s: Student): Student = s.copy(
  firstName = s.firstName.toUpperCase,
  lastName = s.lastName.toUpperCase
)
```